# Get Pull Request Reactions using Github API

Tags: github, github-api

The UI is allowing users to add reactions to the “body” of a pull request. However I don’t seem to be able to find a way to get the reactions on a pull request?

I can see how to get the reactions to comments, but can’t see how to do it in the “body” which is just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to get the linked "issue" for the PR. The Reactions are there.